# Is the Taylor series comparable to Fourier series and spherical harmonics?

Tags: fourier-series, taylor-expansion

I am currently trying to grasp spherical harmonics and try to digest that we proved that the sine and cosine functions are a basis for the $L^2$ space of the squared-integrable functions.

So as far as I have understood it, the functions that can be integrated with $$\int_0^1 \mathrm dx \, f^2(x)$$ are forming a vector space. Then all the $e_n = \cos(n \pi x)$ (and sine) form a basis for that space. So any (even, since I like to drop the sine terms) function $f$ can be represented as a linear combination of the basis vectors like:
$$f = \sum a_n e_n$$

To get the coefficients $a_n$, I need to project the vector (i. e. the function) onto the basis vector (i. e. the sine) using the inner (dot) product, like so:

$$ a_n = \left\langle f(x), e_n \right\rangle_F = \int_0^1 \mathrm dx \, f(x) \cos(n \pi x)$$

Now I was wondering whether the Taylor series is such a representation with orthogonal functions $e_n = x^n$ as well. Is the “Taylor inner product” something like this then?

$$ a_n = \left\langle f(x), x^n \right\rangle_T = \frac{1}{n!} \left. \frac{\mathrm d^n f(x)}{\mathrm d x^n} \right|_{x = 0}$$

In the end, I will have a series like so :

$$ f = \sum a_n e_n =\sum\limits_{n} \frac{1}{n!} \left. \frac{\mathrm d^n f(x)}{\mathrm d x^n} \right|_{x = 0} x^n$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. In short, the reason is because Taylor series are a **local** description of a function, whereas Fourier series and spherical harmonics incorporate **global** data. More precisely, the Taylor series of a smooth function at $0$ doesn't change if you modify the function arbitrarily outside of a neighborhood of $0$.

You are free to introduce an inner product on, say, polynomials given by

$$\langle x^n, x^m \rangle = \delta_{nm}$$

which formally reproduces the Taylor series of a polynomial, but the above argument strongly suggests that this inner product can't be described via integration against a function supported away from $0$, and in addition any integral of the form

$$\langle x^n, x^m \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n x^m g(x) \, dx$$

would have the property that $\langle x^n, x^m \rangle = \langle 1, x^{n+m} \rangle$.

However, in the special case of holomorphic functions, Taylor series can be related to Fourier series using the [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). Intuitively this is because the local behavior of holomorphic functions determine their global behavior.

Comment: Okay, I have not thought about the local/global issue. So the Taylor series cannot be described with a convolution inner product like Fourier series and spherical harmonics since the polynomials would not be orthogonal in any sense?

Comment: @queueoverflow: yes. The local / global distinction also tripped me up when I was first learning about this material, but it is crucial. One issue is that you're used to Taylor series which converge to the functions they describe; this is not the typical situation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). On the other hand, Fourier series always converge in the $L^2$ sense to functions they describe.